# Register an internal package on Pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pypi

I read somewhere that if you make an internal Python package for proprietary work, you should still register the name on PyPi to avoid potential future dependency issues.

How do I do this without posting my code publicly? This package contains code to be used internally at my work. Should I make an empty python package using the name I want to reserve and upload that to PyPi? And then install my package at work using git instead of PyPi?

Uploading an empty package seems like a silly thing to do that would just annoy other people. But I can't find a way to just register the name.

Comment: Namespacing packages would solve your problem. There is a Feature Request for that -> https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/2589

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Since the `register` command is deprecated and not supported anymore](https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#registering-package-names-metadata), you will have to perform the following steps:

1. Create a stub `setup.py` with empty package list, an initial version and the filled out metadata
2. Build and upload the package
3. Go to [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org) and delete the initial package version you just uploaded

This way, the package name will be reserved to you because you are registered as its owner now, but searching for the package will yield no results and any direct access will result in a 404.

Let's say you want to reserve the package name `foo`. Steps:

1. Create a new `setup.py` stub. Make sure `packages` list is empty so you don't upload some code by accident:

   ```
   from setuptools import setup

   setup(
       name='foo',
       version='0.0.1',
       description='',
       long_description='',
       url='https://www.example.com',
       author='me',
       author_email='me@example.com',
       packages=[],
       classifiers=['Development Status :: 1 - Planning'],
   )
   ```
2. Build and upload the package:

   ```
   $ python setup.py bdist_wheel upload
   running bdist_wheel
   running build
   ...
   running upload
   Submitting /tmp/foo/dist/foo-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
   Server response (200): OK
   ```
3. Delete the uploaded wheel: go to the project page `https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=pkg_edit&name=foo`, where you will find the list of uploaded wheels - select one you uploaded and press `Remove`.

Now you have reserved the project name, since no one else will be able to upload a package `foo` unless you give them administrator permissions on PyPI:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel upload
running bdist_wheel
running build
...
running upload
Submitting /tmp/foo/dist/foo-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (403): The user 'bar' is not allowed to upload to project 'foo'. See https://pypi.org/help#project-name for more information.
error: Upload failed (403): The user 'bar' is not allowed to upload to project 'foo'. See https://pypi.org/help#project-name for more information.

$ twine upload dist/foo-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl 
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading foo-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: The user 'bar' is not allowed to 
upload to project 'foo'. See https://pypi.org/help#project-name for 
more information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Any direct access attempts will end in a 404:

```
$ curl -I https://pypi.python.org/pypi/foo
HTTP/2 404
```

Installing via `pip` will fail as expected:

```
$ pip install foo
Collecting foo
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement foo (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for foo
```

#### PEP 541

Note that there is a PEP on *Package Index Name Retention* ([`PEP 541`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0541)) that defines unreachable, abandoned, and invalid projects on the package index. In the section [Name conflict resolution for active projects](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0541/#name-conflict-resolution-for-active-projects), it states:

> None of the following qualify for package name ownership transfer:
>
> ...
>
> User A owns a project X outside the Package Index. User B creates a package under the name X on the Index. After some time, User A wants to publish project X on the Index but realizes name is taken. This is true even if User A's project X gains notability and User B's project X is not notable.

So, although the PEP confirms that no one can take a name of an *active* project away from you, this is not guaranteed in the case of an inactive project which is a good countermeasure against name squatting. My understanding of this is that if you reserve a name now without developing anything and in the future, an open-source project emerges under that name and gets very popular, you can bet the project owner's rights will be taken away from you.

Also, note that empty packages or packages with no functionality can be qualified as an invalid package and be removed:

> A project published on the Package Index meeting ANY of the following is considered invalid and will be removed from the Index:
>
> ...
>
> - project is name squatting (package has no functionality or is empty);
> - project name, description, or content violates the Code of Conduct; or
> - project is abusing the Package Index for purposes it was not intended.

Comment: So would you recommend doing this? Or is it more common / sensible to just not register?

Comment: At the place where I work, we have evaluated this issue for about a year and decided against name squatting. Instead, we have set up our own package repository and use it to distribute the packages to the early bird customers. Technically, there is nothing that prevents you from reserving the package name on PyPI for future use, though.

Comment: In our case, the code is not our product so this would only ever be for internal use. So it sounds like I should just leave it then.

Comment: You won't hear me say this often, but to me, this is one area where Java's packaging naming conventions have Python's beat. I wish I could just name something 'net.mydomain.whatever' and be done with it, even if 'net.mydomain' are just namespace packages.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: @DougR. Anyone else can take your net.mydomain.whatever and upload it to public maven repo.  You will get same issues....

Comment: @Reishin - I certainly understand that anyone else can do this. However, one of the truly wonderful things about the Python community is that (for the most part) people adhere to the established conventions (i.e., MyClass._my_method() is private). If this were an established convention, then I suspect it would receive the same general level of adherence as other Python conventions are.

Answer (score 4):

Does not make to much sense to register in the community index a package that is not public for the community.

To reduce chances of future conflicts, I would prefix the package name with something related to your company (I.e: the name or alias). For instance: mycompany-eventualconflictingname.

Eventually, if you want to make the package public, you will need to update your internal clients requirements. But that seems less worrying than having a name conflict.

Comment: I think that is exactly what the OP wants to do.  Like owning "com.whoever" they don't want somoene else publishing it